# Meaning of bivalent vertices

Tags: graph-theory, terminology

I am studying some simple graph theory, and I'm stuck on the word bivalent vertices. I know that bivalent means that something in the lines of something taking one value out of two possible values. But what does it mean in graph theory?

Answer (score 1):

According to my supervisor, that a vertex is bivalent means that it has only two connected edges.

Edit: Also see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(graph_theory)).

Comment: Are people voting to delete my answer? Is the answer wrong in any way?

Comment: I didn't downvote, and the meaning seems plausible to me, but I have never seen the word "bivalent" used this way, so maybe your answer could be improved with supporting evidence.

Comment: Yes, it seems odd that one would use this word for that meaning. However, my supervisor said so and I trust him. Thanks for your thoughts.

Comment: This is even worse - now I want to ask your supervisor for *his* supporting evidence :)

Comment: Not evidence, but see this article at page 188: https://armj.math.stonybrook.edu/pdf-Springer-final/019-0116.pdf, they don't have any vertices with edges on them

Comment: That's perfectly good evidence as far as I am concerned, thank you :)