# No space can be covered by both of these graphs.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-topology

**The Problem:** I am self studying *Algebraic Topology* by Hatcher, and I ran into the following issue. For an exercise I demonstrated that these graphs have covering spaces $\tilde{X_1}$ and $\tilde{X_2}$ such that $\tilde{X_1}\cong \tilde{X_2}$, and now I am trying to show that there is no **connected** space $X$ that is covered by both $X_1$ and $X_2$. I know that they both simultaneously cover $X_1\sqcup X_2$, but I have a hunch that no such connected space can exist.

[image: The two graphs mentioned above.]

**My Progress:** I have shown that for such a space $X$, $X_1$ and $X_2$ must both be either one or two-sheeted covers by considering the image of $x$ under the covering map. Moreover, I have ruled out the case where either $X_1$ or $X_2$ is a 1-sheeted cover by similar reasoning.

I want to use the fact, but I cannot seem to make it precise: Any orientation of the edges of $X_1$ results in two ingoing edges and one outgoing edge or vice verse at each vertex, while we can orient edges in $X_2$ such that all of the edges incident at a vertex are outgoing or all of them are ingoing.

Alternatively, if I can show that $X$ has a graph structure then it would have to have one vertex as $X_1$ and $X_2$ are two sheeted covers, but then it would have total degree 3, which is odd, but all graphs have even total degree.

Any hints would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is your definition of a "graph structure"?

Comment: Specifically I mean a 1 dimensional CW structure or [graph topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(topology)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose there is a ($2$-sheeted) cover $X_1 \to X$ and pass to a Galois cover $\tilde X \to X_1 \to X$. Now consider the pulled back CW structure on $\tilde X$ as a quotient map $\tilde X_\delta \to \tilde X$, where $\tilde X_\delta$ is a disjoint union of $0$ and $1$ cells. Because $X_1$ and hence $\tilde X$ has no bivalent vertices (ie vertices of degree $2$), for any homeomorphism $\phi$ of $\tilde X$, the map $\tilde X_\delta \to \tilde X \xrightarrow{\phi} \tilde X$ has to take the endpoint of an edge to a vertex (and the interior of the edge maps to an edge incident with that vertex). So the action of the deck group $\Gamma = \Gamma(\tilde X, X)$ on $\tilde X$ (and in fact the whole homeomorphism group of $\tilde X$) lifts to $\tilde X_\delta$. Since the deck group acts freely on $\tilde X$, the action on $\tilde X_\delta$ is determined by the action on the set of vertices and edges. So $\tilde X_\delta/\Gamma$ is a disjoint union of cells and $\tilde X_\delta/\Gamma \to X$ is a CW structure on $X$.

Once you have a CW structure on $X$ the map $X_1 \to X$ is in fact cellular by comparing the local topologies.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term "bivalent vertices". Does this mean $X$ has no vertices of degree 2 as in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4371356/meaning-of-bivalent-vertices)? Additionally, does this assume that $X$ already has the structure of a graph?

Comment: Sorry about the flurry of delete-edit-undeletes. I originally misunderstood the question but I think now this also answers the $1$-dimensional case of [your other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4673681) when the cover has no bivalent vertices.

Comment: This is tremendously helpful!