# Pushforward of CW Structure Under Covering Map

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let $p:\tilde{X}\rightarrow X$ be a covering of a space $X$.
I know that a CW structure on $X$ pulls back to a CW structure on $\tilde{X}$ that agrees with the topology on $\tilde{X}$. Moreover, I know that if $\tilde{X}$ has a CW structure, there is no general way to pushforward this structure onto $X$. Are there certain conditions we can impose on $X$ and $\tilde{X}$ such that this structure does induce a CW structure on $X$ that agrees with the topology on $X$?

Comment: What sort of conditions are you looking for? If $p$ is a Galois cover (which you can ensure by passing to the Galois closure) then it would be enough for the deck group to act by cellular maps.

Comment: In the [definition](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/cellular+map) of cellular map that I am familiar with, we need to know what the CW structure on $X$ is already. Assuming $X$ doesn't a priori have one, can a certain condition on say $p$ induce a cell structure on $X$ from that on $\tilde{X}$?

Comment: I understand the question as: given a CW structure on $\tilde X$, when does it pull back from one on $X$. The deck group acts on $\tilde X$, by homeomorphisms, so it makes sense to ask if these homeomorphisms are cellular.

Comment: Not quite - I meant to ask if we can conclude that $X$ has a cell structure at all - not when this structure pulls back to the structure on $\tilde{X}$.

Comment: In any case it makes sense to ask if the deck group acts by cellular maps.

Comment: @martianpolarbear: So from your most recent comment, your question has become: *If $\tilde X$ is a CW structure, does $X$ have a CW structure?* That seems quite different from what you ask in your post, namely whether the CW structure on $\tilde X$ "induces" a CW structure on $X$. It would help if you could give a precise definition of what you mean by "induces" in this instance.